# WooCommerce Multi-Vendor uploading their videos?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I have created a multi-vendor store on WooCommerce with WCMp plugin. It works fine for non-digital products. But, now i want to let users upload big audio and video files for sale.

The audio/video files should only be available to customers after purchase.

We want each vendor to be able to securely upload *sale-able* videos on *one* location *without having access* to other vendor's digital video products for sale.

These are the problems i found with each of these solutions below:

1. **Website Storage**: Storing these files on hosting platform is not an option due to size limitations.
2. **Vimeo**: I called up Vimeo for their best plan but that would need each vendor to have their own vimeo account to be able to *privately* upload their videos for sale. So, this becomes non acceptable because i’d like all vendors to not worry about storage space subscriptions.
3. **Amazon S3 cloud**: I investigated this also, and once a vendor uploads his videos here, he will have access to all other vendor's uploads as well - which is what we do *not* want.

Is there any other solution which I missed to investigate that will solve this problem  ?

Answer (score 0):

We were able to solve this problem for anyone who stumbles upon this in the future.

We used AWS integration (3rd option)

There is a plugin that we used (called Wordpress Offload Media Lite) which uploads new media files to AWS directly. The setup is pretty simple, and the only caveat with unpaid version is that it does NOT transfer existing files (which we did not need anyways, in our current scenario)